# Update data extension filtering on WHERE function

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

If we're building a data extension through a SQL query and it is set to **Add and Update** and we also use a `where` function like the one below:

```
WHERE c.Optin__c = 'TRUE'
```

If the `Optin__c` field is changed in the source data, will that user be removed from the data extension being built as they no longer meet the where criteria on the SQL query, or would we need to use **Update** to ensure that the data extension remains clean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Data Action type as **Add and Update** when using an SQL query. The only availabe modes are: **Append**, **Update** and **Overwrite**

No, the record will not be removed when using **Append**. The only way a record can be removed from a DE is by using **Overwrite** mode.

> **Append:** Adds a row in the target for each row returned by the SQL
>   query. Rows that exist in the target are not updated.
>
> **Overwrite**: Removes all existing rows in the target and adds new rows
>   from the result of SQL Query.

You'd better use **Update** to keep data clean as you've said.

Check out the Data Action types:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_use_the_sql_query_activity.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: No worries, don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you..

Comment: Just FYI - Update in Query activity is actually 'Add and Update' functionality